# How to set height to an element with ::before selector with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

There is an element with .bg class. The css rules are the following:

```
.bg {
    width:100%;
}

.bg:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and I have a javascript rule, where I am setting the height to bg class:

```
$(".bg").height($(document).height());
```

But I want to set the $(document).height() to .bg:before. How can I achieve this with javascript?
Because `$(".bg:before").height($(document).height());`does not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `pseudo-elements` are well just `pseudo`. You can't select them in Javascript.

Comment: Why don't you just put another element in the HTML before `.bg`, then you can do whatever you want with it?

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript you can modify the rule for `.bg:before` this way.

Loop through the rules in stylesheet, if the current rule is `.bg:before`(`r.selectorText == .bg:before`) , change its `height`(`r.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px'`).

```js
var ss = document.styleSheets;

for (i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
  var rules = ss[i];
  for (j = 0; j < rules.cssRules.length; j++) {
    var r = rules.cssRules[j];
    if (r.selectorText == ".bg:before" || r.selectorText == ".bg::before") {
      console.log('Old rule: ' + r.cssText)
      r.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
      console.log('Modified rule: ' + r.cssText)
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.bg {
  width: 100%;
}
.bg::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea to change the stylesheet rule itself. +1. Just one change though.. `if (r.selectorText == ".bg::before"..`. It should be `::` not `:` because browser will change the non-standard one to standard one by itself.

Comment: No not that.. What I meant was that it should be in the js code. Because even if the CSS contains single `:` colon, the browser will make it double `::` on its own. Then, you won't have to worry about the CSS...the js will work anyways. Hope am able to convey it clearly :)

Comment: @abhitalks - If I make the change in JS, it [doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/m4dyxo38/).

Comment: Works just fine here. Maybe some browser inconsistency again! Forget it. Good answer and that's more worth it.

Comment: @abhitalks - Anyway, I add an or condition (`||`) alongwith `r.selectorText == .bg::before` just in case. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: In my case, I'm using Vue and it adds things like `[data-v-628430e3]` to the selector. To solve this, I simply used a combination of .startsWith() and .endsWith() like so: if I had to select `#headerOffsets[data-v-628430e3] > :first-child::after` I would use: `if (r.selectorText?.startsWith("#headerOffsets") && r.selectorText?.endsWith(" > :first-child::after")) {`. Of course, you could use a .includes() or whatever string manipulation method you want.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't with javascript, because pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a value into the pseudoelement from the main element via a CSS variable.  The main element can be accessed via javascript and that value calculated and updated.  You can also set a fallback value to be used until the value is updated as I have here (your 100%), or by setting a default value for the CSS variable in any parent element's CSS.

All of that in code: Use a `height: var(--bg-height, 100%);` in the pseudoclass and then use `element.style.setProperties('--bg-height',document.body.scrollHeight+'px');` in your javascript.

Note that if you use vanilla js (which I am here, it being 2022), there are some box-model weirdness with certain methods of calculating document height.

A full working example is as follows:

```js
let el = document.getElementById('example');
el.style.setProperty('--bg-height', 
    document.body.scrollHeight+'px');
```

```css
/*************************************************
  The CSS from the question.  I lightened the grey 
  (dropped the transparency from 0.5 to 0.25) and 
  added a var for height.
 ***/

.bg {
  width:100%;
}

.bg:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--bg-height, 100%);
}


/*************************************************
  Following is for this demo and can be removed.
 ***/

:root {
  font: 16px Roboto, Helvetica, Barlow, sans-serif;
}
body {  
}
a { color: #435; }
section>p {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="bg" id="example">
  <p>Here is a section that is the main element being focused on. It has a transparent (thus, white) background.  There is a :before pseudoelement positioned absolutely over it with a highly transparent black (thus a light grey tint).  Using javascript, this pseudoelement is set to a height equal to the document itself.</p>
  <p>Resizing and other things that would change the document height should be taken into account and observed.</p>
  <p>Answer to <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358143/how-to-set-height-to-an-element-with-before-selector-with-javascript">How to set height to an element with ::before selector with javascript?</a></p>
</section>
```